# selenium grid2 and python How to specify environments

Tags: python, selenium, grid

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setBrowserName();
capability.setPlatform();
capability.setVersion()
capability.setCapability(,);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

I need to specific environments (ff-on-xp, ie7-on-xp, etc) to the tests .from above,the example is in java,who can give me an example in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the [WebDriver python docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://local:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER)
driver.start_client()
```